# lombok.config property is not stopping compiler/IDE warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am storing some properties in `lombok.config`, which, I though, is a great way to reduce unnecessary stacks of lombok annotations on my classes. One of these properties is the following;

```
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = CALL
```

I though this would shut the compiler up & end the following IDE (Intellij) warnings about putting an `@EqualsAndHashCode` with `callSuper` value set on those classes with `@Data` and extending some other class;

> Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)` to your type.

It does not though! Is there a way to stop these warnings without adding the `callSuper` property directly on the classes?